# The piano introduction to Pink Martini's "La Soledad"

Tags: identify-this-song, classical-music

Can anyone recognize the piano introduction, at the beginning of Pink Martini's La Soledad, as a classical piano piece?  It sounds very Debussy to me, but I'm not familiar enough to know...

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qSZG3jScmf0

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was Chopin's Andante Spianato et Grande polonaise brillante.  Actually found it down in the comments below the YouTube video I posted. xD